# Installing Apigee on my own server

Tags: apigee

Is it possible to download and install Apigee on your own server? If so, is there any documentation on how to do this?

I have looked around on the [Apigee.com](http://apigee.com/about) web site for details, and I'm aware that there is an [Apigee GitHub](https://github.com/apigee) repo, but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is NO. Apigee does NOT provide you with content that can be downloaded, installed and run locally. However, if you do want to do this, you would need to buy a licensed [OPDK](https://opdk.info/) (On Premise Deployment Kit), and then go about setting things up.

Apigee does provide a FREE account however for you to play around with and perform most/ALL actions, including implementing policies and building developer applications. Navigate to [Apigee Enterprise](http://enterprise.apigee.com), create a free account and plug away.

ALL of the documentation you need can be found at the [Apigee Documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/) site.

Answer (score 2):

Apigee leverages some features from Usergrid, which is an open source project currently incubating at Apache.

http://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/

You can download it and run it on your own server.  It doesn't give you API management, but it does provide BaaS functionality (a backend service/datastore to power mobile apps).

Answer (score 1):

Apigee has a On premise deployment setup(opdk) which lets clients run apigee on their own servers. But i believe it's not a free piece of software, You will have to pay and buy the package which comes with a license for its setup & usage.

http://apigee.com/about/why-apigee

Answer (score 0):

The full suit of Apigee capabilities are absolutely available either in the cloud or on-prem. However, the on-prem option only exists for Apigee Edge and not Developer.